# Create documents in CMIS

Tags: java, cmis

Could you tell me if there is any possibility to create documents which parent would be another document.

```
ObjectId parentId = session.createObjectId(someDocumentStringId);
session.createDocument(properties, parentId, stream, VersioningState.None);
```

Now I get error: **Operation not supported by the repository for this object!**

Answer (score 1):

Documents are not containers in CMIS. Only a folder can be a parent of a document.

Have a look at CMIS relationships. They may solve your problem.